# Editable user info via form

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to build a website where a user, once logged in, can change their contact information.

I am to the point of being able to input the information, but when I log out and log in again the form field is empty again even though the PHPmyadmin entry is there.

I want to be able to update the record of the user, say he changed his phone number.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/user_settings.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "Admin";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "denied_access.html";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE user_settings SET name=%s, phonenumber=%s, email=%s, country=%s, street1=%s, street2=%s, city=%s, `state`=%s, postalcode=%s WHERE userID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_phonenumber'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_country'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_street1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_street2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_city'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_state'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_postalcode'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['settings_userID'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_user_settings, $user_settings);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $user_settings) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_user_settings, $user_settings);
$query_settings_recordset = "SELECT * FROM user_settings";
$settings_recordset = mysql_query($query_settings_recordset, $user_settings) or die(mysql_error());
$row_settings_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($settings_recordset);
$totalRows_settings_recordset = mysql_num_rows($settings_recordset);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body><br />
<nav>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="catalog.php">CATALOG</a></li>
  <li><a href="reporting.php">REPORTING</a></li>
  <li><a href="import_data.php">IMPORT DATA</a></li>
  <li><a class="current" href="settings.php">SETTINGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">SIGN OUT</a><br />
</li></ul></nav>
<nav>
<ul class="nav2">
  <li><a class="current" href="settings.php">Contact Detail </a></li> | 
  <li><a href="settings_payment.php">Payment Details</a></li>
</ul></li></div>
<div>
<h1>SETTINGS (Admin)</h1> 
<strong>CONTACT DETAILS</strong>
<br />
<br /><form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="form">
Name <input name="settings_userID" type="hidden" id="settings_userID" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings UserID"><br />
<input name="settings_name" type="text" id="settings_name" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings Name"><br />
Phone Number <br />
<input name="settings_phonenumber" type="text" id="settings_phonenumber" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings Phonenumber"><br />
E-Mail<br />
<input name="settings_email" type="email" id="settings_email" form="setting_contacts_form" title="Settings Email"><br />
Country<br />
<select name="settings_country">
  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="AT">Austria</option>
  <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select><br />
Street Address 1<br />
<input name="settings_street1" type="text" id="settings_street1" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings Street Adress 1"><br />
Street Address 2<br />
<input name="settings_street2" type="text" id="settings_street2" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings Street Adress 2"><br />
Town/City<br />
<input name="settings_city" type="text" id="settings_city" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings City"><br />
State<br />
<input name="settings_state" type="text" id="settings_state" form="settings_contact_form" title="Settings State"><br />
Postal code<br />
<input name="settings_postalcode" type="text" id="settings_postalcode" form="settinga_contact_form" title="Settings Postal Code"><br />
<br /> 
<input name="Save_button" type="submit" id="Save_button" title="Save" value="  SAVE  "><br />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form" />
</form><br />

<br />
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($settings_recordset);
?>
```

Comment: You're inserting a new data not updating change the insert query to update

Comment: I saw that too, but once i tried the update query nothing changed. once i log in the fields are still empty. replaced the code with the new updated code.

Comment: You're getting the user id wrong get by session

Answer (score -1):

Get User id from the session create a var that has the id of the user when he login